# Form a matrix using MySql data in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a Table in MySQL with thousands rows of data and 3 columns as follows:
 Column1:Hour(in int),
 Column2:DayOfWeek(in int),
 Column3:Power(in double)

How do I form a (thousands rows x 3)matrix in C# console application?
In addition, how do I do a transpose on the matrix?
Below shows part of my code:

```
        List<double> realPowers = new List<double>();

        List<int> dayOfWeek = new List<int>();

        List<int> Hour = new List<int>();
        int rows_count = 0;
        using (MySqlDataReader myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader())
        {
            foreach (DbDataRecord record in myReader)
            {
                realPowers.Add(record.GetDouble(3));
                dayOfWeek.Add(record.GetInt32(2));
                Hour.Add(record.GetInt32(1));
                rows_count++;
            }
        }

        double[] Load = realPowers.ToArray();
        int[] X = dayOfWeek.ToArray();
        int[] Y = Hour.ToArray();

        int[][] matrix = new int[3][];
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.Length; i++)
        {
            matrix[i] = new int[rows_count];
        }
        matrix[0] = X;
```

I am able to form each individual column of data into a single column matrix. But how do I combine the 3 columns of data into a matrix of 3 columns?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two ways:

```
int[][] matrix = new int[3][];
```

or

```
int[,] matrix = new int[3,1000];
```

As your Power is double, you may use type `double` for everything.

If using the first construct you need to 
do a loop and initialize your elements.

```
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.Length; i++)
{
    matrix[i] = new int[1000];
}
```

The first construct is called jagged array (or array of arrays)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx

The second construct is called multidimensional array.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx

Regarding transposing see this example.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    namespace ConsoleApplicationTEST
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                int[,] matrix = new int[5, 8] { 
                   {  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8 }, 
                   {  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 },
                   { 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24 },
                   { 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32 },
                   { 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40 },
                };

                int[,] newArray = new int[8, 5];
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                    for (int r = 0; r < 5; r++)
                        newArray[j, r] = matrix[r, j];

                for (int r = 0; r < 8; r++)
                {
                    for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(newArray[r,c] + " ");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }

                Console.ReadLine();

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of having to type out all the elements in the array that form a matrix, how can I load the data elements from a MySQL table? Since I can't possibly be typing out thousands over of rows of data.

Comment: @Ping This would be a subject of another question. You've changed your question significantly.

Comment: Oh, what type of question would this be categorized under? Sorry. I'm new to this forum.

Comment: @Ping Try MySQL and C# as tags.

Comment: I thought I have already tagged the question as c# and mysql.?

Comment: @Ping Post a new question. New is the key here. You've asked too many questions in one. You need to ask something like 'How do I do data access to a MySQL DB from C#'. Then people will answer specifically about this.